# Is there a way to preserve the original HTTP_REFERER when using Django's redirect?

Tags: django, http-headers

I have a Django site and I'm using Google Analytics to keep track of where my traffic is coming from.

I want to route traffic to various places depending on whether the user is signed in, or has done other stuff.  So in my views.py, I have a function like this:

```
def toDefaultLandingPage(request):
    # tell me who the referrer is
    # this is what I want to pass along in the request if I can
    print(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            configuration = UserData.objects.get(user=request.user)
            return redirect('/home/')
        except:
            # user has not configured their profile yet
            return redirect('/user/')
    else:
        # promo page for non-logged in users
        return redirect('/about/')
```

This works great, except that Google Analytics says that most of my traffic has no referrer.  I know this is a lie, because the print statement in default landing page has either google or facebook in it about 70% of the time.

Is there any way to pass the original referrer to the 3 different redirects I use?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to know what the "right" solution to this is.  I worked around this by calling the views directly:

Instead of `return redirect('/home/')`, I called `return home(request)` where home is a normal function:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'rewrite_url': '/home/',
    }
return render(request,'some_template.html', context=context)
```

The problem with this approach is that the URL is not updated.  So, I use a bit of javascript to change that in `some_template.html`:

```
{% if rewrite_url %}
  <script>
  window.onload = function() {
    history.pushState("{{ rewrite_url }}", "", "{{ rewrite_url }}");
  }
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

Again, this seems a bit hackish, and I would love a cleaner solution.